# Understanding Greatest function with date functions in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The output of the below query is 4, but I don't understand why. What is happening here?

```
SELECT GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3, 0) 
  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into steps:

- `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` is 2020-06-29
- `NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON')` is the next Monday *after* today, which is 2020-07-06
- `NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE)` is the number of days between 2020-06-29 and 2020-07-06, which is 7
- `NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3` is 7 minus 3, which is 4
- `GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3, 0)` is the greater of 0 and 4, which is 4

Perhaps you expected `next_day` to give you today; in which case you need to subtract a day:

```
GREATEST(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3, 0)
```

which gives the answer 0.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NEXT_DAY.html) (emphasis added):

> `NEXT_DAY` returns the date of the first weekday named by `char` that is **later than** the date *date*.

The next Monday that is later than today is *next* Monday, not today.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe003ca7a6beb950c82ebb11ae41d485)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   i was assuming NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) is the number of days between 2020-06-29 and 2020-07-06 as 6.

Comment: There are usually 7 days between Mondays *8-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the result of

`select NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 'MON') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 3 from dual`

is 4